# How to query for data in a Gridview between a day or week or Month or year

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have tried to show my data from database. If I stored some data today, that alone should display in the `GridView`.

I'd like to be able to show by week, month, and year.

My code:

```
public void gettoday()
    {
        con.Open();
        {

            //string strview = "select MRNO,MaterialCode,Description,Specification,Category as Cat,Source as Sor,Population as Pop, StockInStores as Stock,MRRating as Rating,PreparedBy,PreparedDate,CheckedBy,CheckedDate,ApprovedBy,ApprovedDate  from tbl_KKSMaterialRaise where PreparedDate between DateAdd(day,-1,GetDate()) AND DateAdd(day,+1,GetDate())";
            string strview = "select MRNO,MaterialCode,Description,Specification,Category as Cat,Source as Sor,Population as Pop, StockInStores as Stock,MRRating as Rating,PreparedBy,PreparedDate,CheckedBy,CheckedDate,ApprovedBy,ApprovedDate  from tbl_KKSMaterialRaise where PreparedDate between (getdate()-1) and (getdate()+1) order by PreparedDate";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strview, con);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                GridView1.DataSource = ds;
                GridView1.DataBind();
                //SqlDataReader reader = cd.ExecuteReader();
            }

            else
            {
                GridView1.DataSource = null;
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }

        }
        con.Close();


    }
```

Comment: I think this question is actual about querying a date range in Sql see if this [SO search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sql+command+for+date+range) helps

Comment: As I understand "between (getdate()-1) and (getdate()+1)" shows records for today, yes?

Comment: I agree with @MarkHall, the GridView will display whatever you bind it to.  This is all about SQL select filtering.

Answer (score 1):

You would just need to change the `BETWEEN` statement in your `WHERE` clause.  Right now you have:

```
where PreparedDate between (getdate()-1) and (getdate()+1)
```

For a week, you'd need to use something like this:

```
WHERE PreparedDate BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, -7, GETDATE()) AND DATEADD(DAY, 1, GETDATE())
```

You could do similar things for month and year by changing `DATEADD(DAY, -7, GETDATE())` to the appropriate date range.

For month

```
DATEADD(MONTH, -1, GETDATE())
```

And for year:

```
DATEADD(YEAR, -1, GETDATE())
```